# Perfect images of complete Erdős space

Tags: gn.general-topology, hilbert-spaces, dimension-theory

Let $\mathbb P$ denote the space of irrational numbers. In an answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356410/quotients-of-the-irrationals), Taras Banakh showed that the perfect images of $\mathbb P$ are precisely the Polish spaces with no compact neighborhoods. Here, *perfect* means a continuous, closed, surjective mapping with compact point pre-images.

Increasing the dimension slightly, we go from $\mathbb P$ to complete Erdős space $$\mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}=\{x\in \ell^2:x_n\in \mathbb P\text{ for all }n<\omega\}.$$ Here, $\ell^2$ is the Hilbert space of square-summable sequences of real numbers.

**Question 1.**  Is every perfect image of $\mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}$ homeomorphic to $\mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}$?

**Question 2.**  Is $\mathbb P$ a perfect image of   $\mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}$?

Comment: What about the original Erdos space? (Does everybody but I know?)

Comment: @WlodAA That one is usually more difficult to work with because it does not have as many representations, is not Polish, etc.  But that may be a good follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the answer to Question 1 is "no".

According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5398), the Julia set of $f(z)=\pi\sinh(z)$ is equal to the entire complex plane $\mathbb C$, and is the perfect image of a "Cantor bouquet". The endpoint set of any Cantor bouquet is homeomorphic to $\mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}$.  But according to the image below (from the same paper), these endpoints are mapped to a dendritic connected set (see the dark lines including the imaginary axis).   [image]